# can't understand this function from php manual example (return bytes)

Tags: php, function, return

I've seen this function in the php manual but I can't understand how it works , the function is supposed to change the value of file size into bytes.
this is the whole example

```
<?php
/*
Our php.ini contains the following settings:

display_errors = On
register_globals = Off
post_max_size = 8M
*/

echo 'display_errors = ' . ini_get('display_errors') . "\n";
echo 'register_globals = ' . ini_get('register_globals') . "\n";
echo 'post_max_size = ' . ini_get('post_max_size') . "\n";
echo 'post_max_size+1 = ' . (ini_get('post_max_size')+1) . "\n";
echo 'post_max_size in bytes = ' . return_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));

function return_bytes($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }

    return $val;
}

?>
```

what I can't understand is this line

```
$last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
```

and that what called 'G' modifier , and what is $last variable used for?
Thanks in advance ,

Comment: `strlen($val)` is the length of the $val string; `strlen($val)-1` is therefore the offset to the last character in the string; `$val[strlen($val)-1]` gets the last character in the string; `$last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);` gets the last character in the string, forces it to lower case, and assigns it to a variable called `$last`

Comment: The `G` "modifier" is if you have a value in `$val` of something like `2G` (2 gigabytes).... The `$last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);` will return a string value of `g`

Comment: The subsequent math is dangerously dependent on PHP's loose typecasting: `2G` will multiple by 1024 3 times in succession, as as 2*1024*1024*1024 giving `2147483648` which is 2 Gigabytes in bytes

Comment: This really is very lazy coding

Comment: @MarkBaker Oh, wow. That is awful. Somebody thought that was elegant.

Comment: Dependency on loose type conversion of `2G` to `2` when used in mathematical operations; drop-through in `case` statements without comment; very, very lazy.... and if original `$val` had a straight numeric value (e.g. `8388608`, which is perfectly valid in a php.ini) it will give a very wrong result

Answer (score 0):

```
$last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
```

That line of code is getting the last character in `$val`, converting it to lower case, then putting it in the `$last` variable.  That variable is then used in the switch statement to apply a multiplier to the input value.

See [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) for some background information that might be useful to you.